# Body background sourced from PHP variable

Tags: php, html, css

So I'm trying to set the body background tag to a php variable I created, however I can't get it to correctly work.

Here is the simple PHP:

```
<?php
$backGround = "images/backgrounds/grey.png";
?>
```

and here is the HTML I tried which none worked.

```
<body background="<?php echo $backGround; ?>">
<body background="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($backGround); ?>">
```

I found these from preview stack overflow questions but they were about setting PHP variables to image sources. I would have thought it would apply to this as well.

Here's my entire PHP page using some of the suggestions but yet to still work.

```
<?php
$backGround = "images/backgrounds/grey.png";
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Exodus</title>
<link rel=StyleSheet href="styles/main.css" type="text/css" media=screen>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- JS Scripts -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/fader.js"></script>
</head>

<body style= 'background-image: url("<?php echo $backGround; ?>")'>
        <div class="pre-wrap">
            <div id="container">
            <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" alt="Pre Logo" style="display: none; margin: 0 auto;" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="wrap">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: <body style="background-image: url('<?=$backGround; ?>');"> should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - using `backgound` attribute is not recommended by W3C.

What you really need is inline style:

```
<body style="background-image: url('<?php echo $backGround; ?>')">
```

Comment: Didn't work, try looking at my entire page I posted just incase I have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Open generated html - see what in an style attribute. Check your html with developers console. Make sure that path to your image is correct.

Comment: Ahh sorry about my supidty! Having placed it onto my web host it works perfectly. Thanks for also pointing out background isn't recommended.

Answer (score 1):

check this it will work

```
   <body style= 'background-image: url("<?php echo $backGround; ?>")'>
     <body style= 'background-image: url("<?php echo htmlspecialchars($backGround); ?>")'>
```